Send attachment with form
I am trying to send an email on Magento 2 with an attachment. Not being a developer I copied a working module, but the email does not start. Below is the error and the code. Can anyone help me?
Error:
main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: Logicone\DiventaRivenditore\Controller\Index\Submit\Interceptor, Argument 2 passed to Logicone\DiventaRivenditore\Controller\Index\Submit::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Filesystem, instance of Logicone\DiventaVpeople\Magento\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder\Interceptor given, called in /var/www/html/generated/code/Logicone/DiventaRivenditore/Controller/Index/Submit/Interceptor.php on line 14 {"report_id":"b1fff39d75dc35fbf57f1806948f5e7f386dee68a8cad0ccc4d0cb12b33821dc","exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Type Error occurred when creating object: Logicone\\DiventaRivenditore\\Controller\\Index\\Submit\\Interceptor, Argument 2 passed to Logicone\\DiventaRivenditore\\Controller\\Index\\Submit::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\\Framework\\Filesystem, instance of Logicone\\DiventaVpeople\\Magento\\Mail\\Template\\TransportBuilder\\Interceptor given, called in /var/www/html/generated/code/Logicone/DiventaRivenditore/Controller/Index/Submit/Interceptor.php on line 14 at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:131)"} []

submit.php
<?php
namespace Logicone\DiventaRivenditore\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Zend\Mime\Mime;

class Submit extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    
    private $dataPersistor;
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */

    private $fileUploaderFactory;
    private $fileSystem;
    
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    protected $_escaper;

    protected $_resultRedirectFactory;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        \Logicone\DiventaRivenditore\Magento\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_escaper = $escaper;
        $this->_resultRedirectFactory=$context->getResultRedirectFactory();
    }

    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->_resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
        try {

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $is_enabled = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('diventarivenditore/general/IsEnabled', $storeScope);
            $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
            $enabled_link = '';
            if($is_enabled == '1') {
                $enabled_link = $url;
            }
            $post['site_link'] = $enabled_link;
            
            $filesData = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('becomevpeople');

            if ($filesData['name']) {
                try {
                     $uploader = $this->fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'becomevpeople']);
                     $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                     $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                     $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                     $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'pdf', 'docx']);
                     $path = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('becomevpeople');
                     $result = $uploader->save($path);
                     $becomevpeople = 'becomevpeople'.$uploader->getUploadedFilename();
                     $filePath = $result['path'].$result['file'];
                     $fileName = $result['name'];
                     $fileType = $result['type'];
                }catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('File format not supported.'));
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
                }
            } else {
                 $becomevpeople = '';
                 $filePath = '';
                 $fileName = '';
            }

            $emailSender=$this->scopeConfig->getValue('diventarivenditore/general/SenderField', $storeScope);
            $emailSender = ($emailSender != '') ? explode(",", $emailSender) : '';
            $emailTo = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('diventarivenditore/general/ToField', $storeScope);
            $emailTo = ($emailTo != '') ? explode(",", $emailTo) : '';
            $emailCc = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('diventarivenditore/general/CcField', $storeScope);
            $emailCc = ($emailCc != '') ? explode(",", $emailCc) : '';
            $emailBcc = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('diventarivenditore/general/BccField', $storeScope);
            $emailBcc = ($emailBcc != '') ? explode(",", $emailBcc) : '';

            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);
            $error = false;

            $sender = [
                'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['name'].' '.$post['surname']),
                'email' =>  $emailSender, //$this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['email']),
            ];

            $templateTo = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('diventarivenditore/general/email_template', $storeScope);
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateTo) // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // this is using frontend area to get the template file
                    'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                ]
            )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($emailTo)
                ->addCc($emailCc)
                ->addBcc($emailBcc)
                ->setReplyTo($this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['email']),$this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['name'].' '.$post['surname']))
                ->getTransport();
            
            if(file_exists($filePath) && !empty($filePath)) {
                $html = $transport->getMessage()->getBody()->generateMessage("\n");
                $bodyMessage = new \Zend\Mime\Part(Mime::encode(quoted_printable_decode($html), 'utf-8', "\n"));
                $bodyMessage->type = 'text/html';
                $attachment = $this->_transportBuilder->addAttachment(file_get_contents($filePath), $fileName);
                $bodyPart = new \Zend\Mime\Message();
                $bodyPart->setParts(array($bodyMessage,$attachment));
                $transport->getMessage()->setBody($bodyPart);
            }
            
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Your data sent successfully.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('There is some error, Try again.'.$e->getMessage().'<br> TRACE:'.$e->getTraceAsString()));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }
    }


}

?>

customform.phtml
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php 
    $themeHelper = $this->helper('MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data');
    $helperil = $this->helper('Logicone\DiventaRivenditore\Helper\Data');
    $canUsePanel = $themeHelper->acceptToUsePanel();
    $blockObjCou = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Logicone\DiventaRivenditore\Block\Country');
    $blockObjReg = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Logicone\DiventaRivenditore\Block\Region');
    $countryList = $blockObjCou->getCountries();
    $regionsList = $blockObjReg->getRegions();
?>
<?php $diventaRivenditoreEnable = $helperil->getGeneralConfig('IsEnabled'); ?>
<?php if ($diventaRivenditoreEnable  == 0) { ?>
    <?php $diventaRivenditoreRedirect = $helperil->getGeneralConfig('ToRedirect'); ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "<?php echo $diventaRivenditoreRedirect; ?>";
    </script>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="contact-form-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin-bottom60">
                <h3 class="text-uppercase margin-bottom15"><?php echo __('become a reseller'); ?></h3>
                <p class="sub-title margin-bottom30"><em><?php echo __('To better process your request, we ask you to provide us with some useful data in order to get in touch with our area agent.'); ?></em></p>
                <form id="diventarivenditore-form" class="form contact" method="post" action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl()?>diventarivenditore/index/submit" data-mage-init='{"validation": {}}'>
                    <div class="form-group spaceyesno required">
                            <select name="spaceyesno" class="select admin__control-select" data-validate="{required:true}">
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="<?php echo __('Yes'); ?>"><?php echo __('Yes'); ?></option>
                                <option value="<?php echo __('No'); ?>"><?php echo __('No'); ?></option>
                            </select>
                        <label for="spaceyesno"><span><?php  echo __('Do you want to dedicate a space within your store to our collections?') ?></span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group businessname required">
                        <label for="name"><?php echo __('Business name'); ?></label>
                        <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Business name') ?>" value="" class="input-text form-control" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group email required">
                        <label for="email"><?php echo __('Email'); ?></label>
                        <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text form-control" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group telephone required">
                        <label for="telephone"><?php echo __('Phone'); ?></label>
                        <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone') ?>" value="" class="input-text form-control" type="text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-phoneLax':true}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group shopyesno required">
                        <label for="shopyesno"><span><?php  echo __('Do you already have a shop?') ?></span></label>
                        <select name="shopyesno" class="select admin__control-select" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                            <option value="<?php echo __('Yes'); ?>"><?php echo __('Yes'); ?></option>
                            <option value="<?php echo __('No'); ?>"><?php echo __('No'); ?></option>
                        </select>
                        
                    </div>
                    <?php $diventaRivenditoretiponegozio = $helperil->getGeneralConfig('tiponegozio'); ?>
                    <?php $array_tiponegozio = explode(',', $diventaRivenditoretiponegozio); ?>
                    <div class="form-group field tiponegozio required">
                        <label for="tiponegozio"><span><?php  echo __('Tipologia di attività commerciale') ?></span></label>
                        <select name="tiponegozio" onchange="showDiv(this)">
                            <?php foreach ($array_tiponegozio as $tiponegozio) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo trim($tiponegozio) ?>"><?php echo trim($tiponegozio) ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="hidden_div" style="display:none;" class="form-group field altro required">
                        <label for="tiponegozio"><span><?php  echo __('Specificare altra Tipologia') ?></span></label>
                        <input name="altro" id="altro" title="<?php echo __('Specificare altra Tipologia') ?>" value="" class="input-text form-control" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                    </div>                  
                    <div style="display:none;" class="form-group field country required">
                        <label for="country"><span><?php echo __('Country') ?></span></label>
                        <select name="country">
                            <?php foreach ($countryList as $key => $country) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $country['value'] ?>"><?php echo $country['value'] ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group field region required ">
                        <label for="region"><span><?php  echo __('Region') ?></span></label>
                        <select name="region">
                            <?php foreach ($regionsList as $key => $regions) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $regions['value'] ?>"><?php echo $regions['value'] ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group city required">
                        <label for="city"><?php echo __('City'); ?></label>
                        <input name="city" id="city" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('City') ?>" value="" class="input-text form-control" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group street required">
                        <label for="street"><?php echo __('Street'); ?></label>
                        <input name="street" id="street" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street') ?>" value="" class="input-text form-control" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group postcode required">
                        <label for="postcode"><?php echo __('Post code'); ?></label>
                        <input name="postcode" id="postcode" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Post code') ?>" value="" class="input-text form-control" type="text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-number':true}"/>
                    </div>
                    <?php $diventaRivenditoreMqShop = $helperil->getGeneralConfig('MqShop'); ?>
                    <?php $array_mqShop = explode(',', $diventaRivenditoreMqShop); ?>
                    <div class="form-group field mqshop required">
                        <label for="mqshop"><span><?php  echo __('Mq Shop') ?></span></label>
                        <select name="mqshop">
                            <?php foreach ($array_mqShop as $mqShop) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo trim($mqShop) ?>"><?php echo trim($mqShop) ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <?php $diventaRivenditoreLocationShops = $helperil->getGeneralConfig('LocationShops'); ?>
                    <?php $array_locationShops = explode(',', $diventaRivenditoreLocationShops); ?>
                    <div class="form-group field locationshops required">
                        <label for="locationshops"><span><?php  echo __('Location Shops') ?></span></label>
                        <select name="locationshops" onchange="showDiv(this)">
                            <?php foreach ($array_locationShops as $locationShops) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo trim($locationShops) ?>"><?php echo trim($locationShops) ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <?php $diventaRivenditoreLocationCity = $helperil->getGeneralConfig('LocationCity'); ?>
                    <?php $array_locationCity = explode(',', $diventaRivenditoreLocationCity); ?>
                    <div id="hidden_div" style="display:none;" class="form-group field locationcity required">
                        <label for="locationcity"><span><?php  echo __('Location City') ?></span></label>
                        <select name="locationcity">
                            <option value="<?php echo __(' '); ?>"><?php echo __(' '); ?></option>
                            <?php foreach ($array_locationCity as $locationCity) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo trim($locationCity) ?>"><?php echo trim($locationCity) ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <?php $diventaRivenditoreHowfindus = $helperil->getGeneralConfig('Howfindus'); ?>
                    <?php $array_howfindus = explode(',', $diventaRivenditoreHowfindus); ?>
                    <div class="form-group field howfindus required">
                        <label for="howfindus"><span><?php  echo __('How did you hear about our company?') ?></span></label>
                        <select name="howfindus" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            <?php foreach ($array_howfindus as $howfindus) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo trim($howfindus) ?>"><?php echo trim($howfindus) ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group howfindother required" style="display:none">
                        <label for="howfindother"><?php echo __('Other'); ?></label>
                        <input name="howfindother" id="howfindother" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Other') ?>" value="" class="input-text form-control" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}" />
                    </div>  

                    <div class="form-group becomevpeople shopimage">
                        <label for="becomevpeople"><?php echo __('Shop Image (max 5 MB)'); ?></label> 
                        <input id="file-btn" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .pdf" name="becomevpeople" type="file" value="">
                        <div id="shopimage_file_error" class="mage-error message-error error message" style="display:none;"><?php echo __('File is too large'); ?></div>
                    </div>                  

                    <div class="diventarivenditore">
                        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Block\Agreements')->setTemplate('additional_agreements.phtml') ->toHtml() ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="contact-frm" id="contact-frm" class="action submit btn btn-primary"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Send Messages') ?></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin-bottom60">
                <!-- Static block contact_page_custom_block -->
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('contact_page_custom_block')->setCanUsePanel($canUsePanel)->toHtml(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="howfindus"]').on('change', function() {
            var options = $(this).find('option');
            // Controllo quale sia l'ultimo valore
            var lastOptionValue = options.last().val();
            // Mostra/nascondi div in base al valore selezionato
            if ($(this).val() === lastOptionValue) {                
                $('.howfindother').slideDown();
            } else {
                $('.howfindother').slideUp();
            }
        });
        // Upload control size
        var uploadField = document.getElementById("file-btn");
        uploadField.onchange = function() {
            if(this.files[0].size > 5294304){
                $('#shopimage_file_error').show();
                this.value = "";
            }else{
                $('#shopimage_file_error').hide();
            };
        };

    });
});
</script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*function showDiv(select){
            var i = ' ';
            i = '<?php echo trim($array_locationShops[2]); ?>';
           if(select.value == i){
            document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "block";
           } else{
            document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "none";
           }
        } */
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*function showDiv(select){
            var i = ' ';
            i = '<?php echo trim($array_tiponegozio[1]); ?>';
           if(select.value == i){
            document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "block";
           } else{
            document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "none";
           }
        } */
    </script>
    <?php $diventaRivenditoreTermsEnable = $helperil->getGeneralConfig('display_terms'); ?>
    <style>
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) { ?>
            <?php if ($i != $diventaRivenditoreTermsEnable) { ?>
                .diventarivenditore #agreement__<?php echo $i ;?> {
                    display:none;
                }
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </style>
<?php } ?>

Any ideas? Thank you

It looks like an issue with the constructer param related -
The constructor of your Logicone\DiventaRivenditore\Controller\Index\Submit class is expecting Magento\Framework\Filesystem as the second argument.
However, instead of receiving an instance of Magento\Framework\Filesystem, it's receiving an instance of Logicone\DiventaVpeople\Magento\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder\Interceptor,
So can you please try once code like this -
 <?php

namespace Logicone\DiventaRivenditore\Controller\Index;

class Submit extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
private $fileSystem;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem
){
parent::__construct($context);
$this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
}

public function execute()
    {
      // your code
   }
}

Then just add one by one parameter in the constructor that you need this can help you to where the issue is there. And the latest Magento 2.4.6, 2.4.7 deprecated Zend so you can use the laminas instead of the Zend class
